# Get evenly distributed points along a Vector line at approximately defined distance

Tags: c#, distance, vectormath

So i have rolled a method which returns me a set of points at a given distance.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets all the points between a two vectors at given distance, including the starting and the ending point.
    /// </summary>
    public static List<Vector2> GetPointsAlongTwoVectors(Vector2 startingPoint, Vector2 endingPoint, float distance)
    {
        Vector2 direction = (endingPoint - startingPoint).normalized;
        float totalDistance = (endingPoint - startingPoint).magnitude;
        float increasingDistance = 0.0f;
        List<Vector2> points = new List<Vector2>();

        points.Add(startingPoint);

        if (totalDistance > distance)
        {
            do
            {
                increasingDistance += distance;
                points.Add(startingPoint + increasingDistance * direction);
            } while (increasingDistance + distance < totalDistance);
        }

        points.Add(endingPoint);

        return points;
    }
```

The method works, but what i eventually want to do next is to spread those points evenly across the given vector.This leads me thinking that the distance will eventually will turn to approximate distance since it will be maybe impossible to get evenly spread points with totally exact distance, but that is alright as soon as the method returns the start point, the end point and the evenly distributed points between them.Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Do you mean that, for example if you have vector (1,1) and (3,3) and you specify '3' for # points, you will get points: (1,1), (2,2) and (3,3)? That is not difficult to program. Or do you mean something different?

Comment: Close enough with the exception you don't specify N number of points but the approximate length which you want them placed.In my situation i don't care how many points are placed as soon as i get them evenly distributed

Comment: So if you have start of (0,0) and end of (0,5) and a distance of 3 you want (0,0), (0,2.5), and (0,5) instead of (0,0), (0,3), and (0,5)?  If so then you can determine the number of sections between points by taking the ceiling of total distance divided by the desired distance, then use that to find the closest distributed distance (total distance divided by the number of sections).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe add this code:

```
...
float totalDistance = (endingPoint - startingPoint).magnitude;
float sectionsCount = (float)Math.Round(totalDistance / distance, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
distance = totalDistance / sectionsCount;
...
```

Be sure to check the case where `sectionsCount` is 0.

Comment: I would rename `pointCount` as it is actually the count of sections between points which is one less than the actual point count (or 2 if it is 0).  Otherwise I think this is correct.

Comment: Exactly the thing i was looking for.Thanks.

Comment: @juharr: you're right. I'm a proponent of good variable naming. Because it is possible that (more) people are copying/pasting the code, it would be good that the variables have correct names. I changed it in the code fragment.